# select distinct of one column and getting values of other columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the data of a table without duplicating the column name but getting the other column values of the same distinct column,

for example, this is my table

```
id | name   | position | salary
1  | hashem | software | 1000
2  | hashem | developer| 2000
3  | hashem | backend  | 3000
```

I am expecting the output to be like

```
name  | position1| position2 | position3 | salary1 | salary2 | salary3
hashem| software | developer | backend   | 1000    | 2000    | 3000
```

What is the perfect query to do this?

***UPDATED: SOLUTION NO NEED TO GO FOR PIVOT:***

THE QUERY TO BE LIKE THIS:

```
SELECT 
sub_service_name,
substring_index(substring_index(positions,',',-3),',',1) as position1,
substring_index(substring_index(positions,',',-2),',',1) as position2,
substring_index(substring_index(positions,',',-1),',',1) as position3,

substring_index(substring_index(salaries,',',-3),',',1) as salary1,
substring_index(substring_index(salaries,',',-2),',',1) as salary2,
substring_index(substring_index(salaries,',',-1),',',1) as salary3

from 
(SELECT tablename.name, GROUP_CONCAT(tablename.position) as 'positions', GROUP_CONCAT(tablename.salary) as 'salarie' from tablename groub by name  ) as result
```

Comment: This is "pivot". Not solvable by single query. Use stored procedure with dynamic SQL.

Comment: and searching with _mysql pivot_ will find you plenty of existing questions and answers on it

Comment: @AntonyJack I just saw this question and I am checking the answer